# ADI BF533 programmable flag interrupt

Tags: embedded, interrupt

When I press PF8 button, I want the blackfin goes into a ISR and the counter increases 1.
I should clear or set a bit which indicates the processor has entered the ISR, but I don't know how to clear it.

My processor is BF533.

Here is my code:

```
    // prototype
EX_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(FlagA_ISR);

volatile int count = 0;

void main(void)
{

     // Register FlagA ISR to interrupt vector group 12
     register_handler(ik_ivg12, FlagA_ISR);

     // set direction of programmable flag PF8 to input
     *pFIO_DIR &= ~PF8;
     ssync();

     // interrupt enable PF8
     *pFIO_INEN |= PF8;
     ssync();     

     // give interrupt when FIO_FLAG_D PF8 changes
     *pFIO_MASKA_D |= PF8;
     ssync();


     // Bind FlagA interrupt to IVG12
     *pSIC_IAR2 |= 0x00005000; // flag A IVG12
     ssync();


     // Enable PFA in system interrupt mask register
     *pSIC_IMASK = 0x00080000;
     ssync();

     // enable IVG12 in core interrupt mask register
     *pIMASK |= 0x00001000;
     ssync();

     // wait for interrupt
     while(count < 5);
        printf("5 interrupts received");
}

EX_INTERRUPT_HANDLER(FlagA_ISR)
{     
     count++;

     // Needed to clear or set a bit to indicate that the processor has entered the ISR
}
```

Comment: Your formatting is broken, please fix it - use the `{}` button and check the preview.  Also, you haven't said why you feel compelled to set or clear a bit, that's done automatically by the compiler or processor on most systems.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer   I will take care the format next time. But the compiler didn't do anything about it.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button on the question to fix it *this time*.  When other people have the same problem and arrive here, they will benefit from properly formatted content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured out how to solve this question.

The PFx are connected to the FIO_FLAG. We can clear our interrupt status by clearing FIO_FLAG.

Here is the code:

```
*pFIO_FLAG_D &= ~PF8;
ssync();
//or, you can try:
*pFIO_FLAG_C |= PF8; 
ssync();
```